# Value from database into html

Tags: php, html, database

I am a beginner to programming in PHP and HTML. I have made a progress bar in CSS and HTML which works great, but I want the pixels of the progress bar to be a value from my database. I got a database with one row and one value.

This is the code I have for the progress bar:

```
<div id="bar4" style="height: 50px;">
  <span style="width: 200px;"></span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the current value (the `200` in `200px`) to a value from my database? I have made a PHP file which echo the value which I thought might make the process easier.

Comment: You need to get the value from the database first. That involves connecting to the database and querying it. I suggest you read up on PHP PDO and take it from there.

Comment: Is a javascript solution ok?

Comment: @TobiasNilsson Please, do post a Javascript solution that connects to a server-side database. :)

Comment: @vanneto I never mentioned going straight to the db from js.

Comment: @TobiasNilsson it's all up to abstraction anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="bar4" style="height: 50px;"><span style="width: <?php HERE GOES YOUR PHP CODE THAT ECHO THE 200 ?>px;"></span>
```

Save the file with PHP extension

Comment: I didnt get that to work. the php code was shown in the browser

Answer (score 0):

you can change. Just assume, you are fetching width from database in a variable $widthVal. Then you have to use something like this

```
<div id="bar4" style="height: 50px;"> <span style="width: <?php echo $widthVal; ?>px;"></span>
```